# how can I make highlight markers in highchart

Tags: highcharts

Is there anyway to make the vertical blue lines as shown in this picture via highcharts/highstock ?

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XsbhyFiwhBs/UV8KjDTUHuI/AAAAAAAAZuU/lsnSXsYXJs4/s1600/Unemploy26Mar2013.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. These are called [`plotBands`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands). Very much recommended to check out the HighCharts API documentation. Plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes these are called plot bands,

you can configure plotbands as you want.

these can be configured easily

```
xAxis :{
plotBands:{
id: 'abc',
from: 0,
to:1,
color: '#CCCCCC'
}
}
```

this will set a plot band with that id from xAxis 0 to xAXis 1,
the id will be useful for removing it later if wanted.

you can also add plot bands once the chart is completely rendered by using the method called addPlotBand();

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
    id: 'abc',
    from: 0,
    to:1,
    color: '#CCCCCC'
});
```

the same can be done for yAxis also.

please refer High
hope this will help you.charts Api documentation before you proceed.